# How to set local timezone in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, timezone, laravel-5

Is there a way to set local timezone in laravel?

In **config/app.php**

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

- What should be added so that timezone value above uses local timezone?

After some research, stumbled upon the following PHP way of dealing with it:

```
$userTimezone = Auth::user()->timezone;

date_default_timezone_set($userTimezone);

// and change the configuration so they match

Config::set('app.timezone', $userTimezone)
```

But, Is there an elegant solution for this other than converting the timezone using the above code.

Cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't do that. Never set the global Laravel timezone to user's timezone. You'll face endless problems.

Choose you application timezone, set the Laravel config to that timezone and never change it.

Instead, when you need to show a date in user's timezone do something like

```
User::find(1)->foobazed_at->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);
```

To control which model columns are automatically converted to `Carbon\Carbon` instances, add the following method to your model file:

```
public function getDates()
{
    return array('foobazed_at', static::CREATED_AT, static::UPDATED_AT, static::DELETED_AT);
}
```

Comment: Make sense...What your suggesting is to keep the timezone UTC itself and alter it while displaying only. ? While beautifying date format to say `"a few min ago"`, will this ever say `"10 min from now"`. We're dealing with `created_at/updated_at` default values in db.

Comment: Yes, keep the App timezone fixed. Make  conversion when you dislay, not when you store. UTC is a great choice since it's universal and has no daylight savings. To show human friendly relative dates you can use [`->foobazed_at->timezone($timezone)->diffForHumans()`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: what about when you need to do some queries with dates in db? for example u stored UTC date, but now user from new york, and you want to see if he already has some entries in the db for today?

Comment: Then you need to do the convert the dates to the desired timezone. You can do it either before the query with Carbon (which is included with Laravel) either on the fly using DB functions (for instance Mysql's CONVERT_TZ function)