# Laravel: How to deal with dates in different timezones

Tags: laravel, timezone

A lot of questions have been asked about this subject. The best answer that I found is this one: [How to set local timezone in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475014/how-to-set-local-timezone-in-laravel)
So the main rule is to keep all database entries in the same timezone.

But I have a specific case where this answer does not work for me. For some models, I have only a date (no datestamp). Example: suppose that I only store the date of when this question was asked (= 2018-01-25). However in Europe it is already 2018-01-26. Someone has a solution for this?

Changing my date field to a datestamp? What with existing dates?

Comment: Let the server set the timestamp, synched to it's own date/time - then just render the displayed time locally with your front end stuff. I don't think you'd want to allow anyone to store their own timestamps into the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're *only* talking about a date, then there is no time component and thus time zones are irrelevant.  For this reason, most platforms do not have a separate date-with-zone type.

You're correct that not every time zone experiences the same date at all times, and that the start of a date and the end of the date occur at different times in different time zones.  However, did you notice that in the prior sentence that I had to use the word "time" to rationalize about these points?  :-)

Because date and time zone don't come together without *time*, there's no purpose in keeping them in the same field.  Instead, keep two fields in your model - one for the date, and one for the time zone.  In many cases, you may even find they belong in two different models.

As a use case example, consider birthdays.  Mine is `1976-08-27`.  That's all it is - just a date.  The time zone of my birth is irrelevant, and so is the time zone I'm located in - *until* I want to evaluate whether it's currently my birthday (or how long until my birthday, etc.)  For those operations, my current time zone is important, and so is the start time-of-day and end time-of-day of that time zone.  Thus - two different fields.

Comment: Framework already implements Carbon on `$dates`, so, instead of recommending to have a separated field for timezone, it should be useful to just store a full datetime with timezone (as timestamp fields), as this allows to auto-convert the timezone directly when is display as `Y-m-d`, instead of manually calculate it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this library [jamesmills/laravel-timezone](https://github.com/jamesmills/laravel-timezone)

OR

If you need custom configuration:

1. Configure your app timezone to UTC.

   'timezone' => 'UTC',
2. You can store different timezones in database column.
3. When outputting/displaying dates, just format it to use that timezone.

   $timezone = 'America/Vancouver';
   $model->created_at->setTimezone($timezone);

**created_at** and **updated_at** are automatically converted to carbon instances, which makes this easier. If you have other dates that you're using, add them to the [protected $dates array on the model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) and laravel will convert them to carbon instance too. Then you can use carbons setTimezone() to change the date/time to the timezone.