# Convert database time and date into user local time using php in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

The default timezone in the laravel application is UTC and I'm creating a chat application that needs to show the user the time they are sending and receiving messages. Javascript seems to be very easy to convert the database time to the user's local timezone, I used the moment.js library to do this conversion in Javascript but now I don't want to use Javascript I want to use PHP to do the conversion. The problem with using PHP is that it is not converting the time to the actual user timezone, for example, my timezone is UTC+1 but I can only use UTC in PHP.

This is what the Javascript code looks like:

```
let time = moment.utc(data.created_at).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

And this is what the PHP code looks like:

```
{{date('H:i', strtotime($data->created_at))}}
```

I want to convert the database time to the user's local time using the user's timezone. The Javascript code works fine but the PHP is not working fine. For the UTC+1 the PHP code is an hour slow.

Comment: Where do you have the information which time zone the user is in stored, and where have you tried to set it as the timezone to use?

Comment: PHP works on the server, so if you setup the timezone to UTC, then you'll get UTC time. You can set the timezone manually. Example with Carbon as you're using Laravel: `$data->created_at->timezone('Asia/Bishkek')`

Comment: I'm not a js expert but I believe that .local is using the browser's timezone.  I don't think its possible to do that server side unless you first resolve the timezone from the request, or ask the user for their choice of timezone.  This package might help https://github.com/jamesmills/laravel-timezone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475014/how-to-set-local-timezone-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't rely on `strtotime()` or similar methods that "magically" know what format your date is. They *guess*. Educated guesses, but still guesses.
2. Use PHP's family of DateTime classes that are properly aware of timezones without mucking about with system-level settings.

```php
$in_str   = '2022-07-13 12:34:56';
$in_date  = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $in_str, new DateTimezone('UTC'));
$out_date = $in_date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('America/Chicago'));

var_dump(
    $in_date->format('c'),
    $out_date->format('c')
);
```

Output:

```
string(25) "2022-07-13T12:34:56+00:00"
string(25) "2022-07-13T07:34:56-05:00"
```

Lastly, I think you might have it backwards. You should be formatting the date/time for human eyeballs as the *last* thing before displaying it, eg: in Javascript. Everything for backend computation/storage [eg: PHP stuff] should ideally be in a single timezone, and that timezone should ideally be UTC for consistency's sake.

Javascript also has the benefit of running in the browser where it can access the user's timezone preference which is notably *not* sent in HTTP requests by default. If you want PHP to know about it, you'll have to write some Javascript to send it anyways.